# Efeito hover com javascript chamando classe css

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-hover

Quero substituir a classe 'produto' pela classe 'produtocomprar' com javascript, assim que passar o mouse pela div. Como faço esse código?

Js

```
$(function(){
$(".produto").hover(
function(){
//Ao posicionar o cursor sobre a div
$(this).addClass('produtocomprar');
},
function(){
//Ao remover o cursor da div
$(this).removeClass('produtocomprar');
        }
    );
```

Css

```
.produto {  
 position: relative;  
 width: 190px;  
 height: 340px;  
 margin-left: 40px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 float: left;  
 display: flex;  
 flex-direction: column; 
 background-color: #ffffff; 
} 

.produtocomprar {
position: relative;  
width: 200px;  
height: 340px;  
margin-left: 40px;
margin-top: 20px;
float: left;  
display: flex;  
flex-direction: column; 
background-color: red; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o método `toggleClass` no `.hover`:

```js
$(function(){
   $(".produto").hover(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('produtocomprar produto');
   });
});
```

```css
.produto {  
 position: relative;  
 width: 190px;  
 height: 340px;  
 margin-left: 40px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 float: left;  
 display: flex;  
 flex-direction: column; 
 background-color: #ffffff; 
} 

.produtocomprar {
position: relative;  
width: 200px;  
height: 340px;  
margin-left: 40px;
margin-top: 20px;
float: left;  
display: flex;  
flex-direction: column; 
background-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="produto">Passe o mouse</div>
```

> Usando apenas um callback no `.hover`, os dois eventos do método são
>   chamados alternadamente quando o mouse entra e quando sai, já que o
>   código a ser executado é o mesmo para os dois eventos.